# $http get null when use phone browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use $http to make a POST request to get my imugur access token, and everything work fine on my PC browser.

But when I use my android phone(ios not sure, haven't tried it), I get an error and from the console.log I see NULL.

I have no idea how to fix this, can anyone help?
Thanks

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token",
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
   transformRequest: function (obj) {
      var str = [];
      for (var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
   },
   data: { client_id: "my_cliendID", client_secret: "my_clientSecret", grant_type: "refresh_token", refresh_token: "my_refreshToken" }
   }).success(function (e) {
      callback(e);
   }).error(function (e) {
      console.log(e); 
   });
```

=========================================================.

when I use $http I get the NULL value, so I try to use $resource but still the same issue. PC work fine, but when use phone I still get an error from `function (error) {alert(JSON.stringify(error))});` now I get some response instead of NULL value. (refer to [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfBrX.jpg))

```
var token = $resource("https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token", null, {gettoken: {method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}

function getAccess(callback) {
   data= { client_id: "my_cliendID", 
      client_secret: "my_clientSecret", 
      grant_type: "refresh_token", 
      refresh_token: "my_refreshToken" 
   }

   var toke = token.gettoken($httpParamSerializer(data),
   function (success) { 
      alert(JSON.stringify(success))
      responseSuccess(success, null, callback) 
   },
   function (error) { 
      alert(JSON.stringify(error))
      responseError(error, callback) 
   });
};
```

Comment: Did you check whether your phone is getting the latest version of code instead of some old cache?

Comment: Perhaps a networking problem. Is your phone connecting behind a different firewall than your desktop?

Comment: Would suggest using the remote debugging in chrome to see what's going on exactly

Comment: building on @shaunhusain's suggession, visit this link once https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Hi all, I updated my question, if I use $resource, it got the error response instead of getting NULL value. But still the same, only PC work fine

Answer (score 0):

after I tried with jquery ajax, it work on both side(PC & mobile)

Don't know why angular $http & $resource not working on mobile browser.

```
data= { client_id: "client_id", 
   client_secret: "client_secret", 
   grant_type: "refresh_token", 
   refresh_token: "refresh_token" 
}
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token',
   data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data), 
   headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   },
   success: function(res) {
      callback(res);
   },
   error:function(res){
   }
});
```

Comment: Makes sense that $resource won't work if $http doesn't work because $resource just uses $http to handle the actual AJAX part of the work.  $http is basically the same as $.ajax though so hard to say what's going wrong for you there.  If using Ionic maybe you need to use the whitelist plugin but I would think that would also apply to $.ajax

Comment: You may also want to step through the source to see what line it dies on if you don't get any sort of error when doing remote debugging. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L940  Ultimately uses this function to send the request https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1222  All the XHR work is in here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js  Not using $http means you'll have to trigger an $apply after updating vars for the view to update.